# Can VSCode do block-comments line-by-line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

Here's an example of me using `ctrl + /` to comment HTML code in VS Code:

```html
    <!-- </label>
    <label>Confirm Your Email:
        <!-- <input type="email" name="emailConfirm" required>
    <!-- </label>
    <label> -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="termsAgree" required/>
            I agree to the <a href="/legal/terms/">Terms & Conditions</a>. -->
    </label> -->
```

1. Selected the whole block of code & `ctrl+/` to comment the whole thing
2. Selected a chunk of code & `ctrl+/` to **un**comment a single line, but it just adds a new comment, thus breaking the larger comment
3. Do #2 again & now it's a nightmare

I have the same problem when I `ctrl + /` CSS Code blocks. Don't have the problem in PHP code, since that uses `//` to comment line-by-line

### How can I change this behavior?

I'm thinking either:

- a "smart" commenter that can use the block comments & "know" whether it's currently in a comment or not
- a dumb commenter that just comments/uncomments every line individually like so:

```html
<!-- </label> -->
<!-- <label>Confirm Your Email: -->
    <!-- <input type="email" name="emailConfirm" required> -->
</label>
<label>
    <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="termsAgree" required/> -->
        <!-- I agree to the <a href="/legal/terms/">Terms & Conditions</a>. -->
<!-- </label> -->
```

Please ignore the fact that the html is invalid. It was just a random block that I used for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made an extension, [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments), that uses your "dumb approach" to toggle each line individually.

Here is a demo on your code that works well:

[image: toggle comments line-by-line]

---

---

Original answer:

Yes, vscode can do block comments by line but that functionality is not built-in.  You will have to use a macro command, here I used [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), to break the lines apart and apply a block comment to each.

Put this into your `settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.blockHTMLCommentByLine",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
      "cursorHomeSelect",
      "editor.action.blockComment",
      "cancelSelection",
    ]
  }
]
```

It break your your selection into separate lines and then toggles a block comment on each line.

Add the keybinding to trigger that macro - over-loading the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> keybinding (put this in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.blockHTMLCommentByLine" },
  // "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|css|scss)/"
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && resourceExtname =~ /\\.html/"
},
```

I restricted it to `.html` files but you can see how to include other extensions in the other `when` clause.

Demo:

[image: toggle block comments each line]

---

You do have to select the complete line if you want the entire line commented.

Comment: This was great! I made some minor modifications for mine. For file-ext, `resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|css|scss|php)/`. For the command `"sequence"`, I used: `"sequence": [ "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected", "editor.action.addCommentLine", ]`. The version you shared inserted comments at the beginning of my lines... before the html started.

Comment: And I found the `addCommentLine` command on https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command. Oh, plus... it's commenting the whole line for me, regardless of selecting the full line.