How to make line-by-line/multiline comments in VS Code in CSS?
I want to make comments from WebStorm like this:
/*.container {*/
/*    display: flex;*/
/*    align-items: center;*/
/*    justify-content: center;*/
/*    position: relative;*/
/*}*/

but in VS Code I get this:
/* .logo {
width: 71.92px;
height: 52.7px;
z-index: 12;
} */

I tried to use Emmet, rewrap extension but it is not work like I want.
upd:
i try to use toggle line comments and it work on half
ex with toggle line comments
another one
another one
another one

have you tried multi Cursors on each line you want to comment and press Ctrl+/

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205176/836330 - I made an extension that does what you want.

@Mark I tried it, but it only works half the time.
almost right, but not quite right.

"Only works half the time"?  Can you explain that please.

try using the Extensions Better Comments or Custom Snippets

You can make use of the inbuilt ability, keep your cursor on line you want, use ctrl+alt+down till cursors are on all line, then do ctrl-/
Also you can multiselect using the mid mouse wheel(if you didn't knew) which has a third button

instead of selecting text by dragging cursor across portion of code using a continuous left button press you can use this button which is below scroll.
